# How to create producer in String Cloud Stream Functional Model (v3.1+)?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

How can I create producer in Spring Cloud Stream Functional Model?
The following version is deprecated now.

```
@Output(OUTPUT)
MessageChannel outbound();
```

I know that it is possible to achieve by java `Supplier` functional class, but it will send message every one second. I don't need it to send every second. I am going to replace REST API with with Kafka.

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `StreamBridge` - see [Sending data to an arbitrary output](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources).

> Here we autowire a `StreamBridge` bean which allows us to send data to an output binding effectively bridging non-stream application with `spring-cloud-stream`. Note that preceding example does not have any source functions defined (e.g., `Supplier` bean) leaving the framework with no trigger to create source bindings, which would be typical for cases where configuration contains function beans. So to trigger the creation of source binding we use `spring.cloud.stream.source` property where you can declare the name of your sources.

Comment: is there any cleaner way to publish a message (in a functional way) without using the `StreamBridge` object and passing the binding name? That looks to me (at least partially) as a hard-coding, by using the defined binding name.

Is there a cleaner way to use a defined Producer (Function or Supplier), instead of the `StreamBridge` object?

Comment: Don’t ask new questions on old (2.5 years) answers. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a stream from an external Kafka topic, you can also bind a spring cloud steam processor’s input to that topic. The stream bridge provides a layer of abstraction that may be cleaner, I.e., your non-stream application does not use the Kafka API directly.